# Storing data in session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I am looking through the [Ruby on Rails tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out) by Michael Hartl. In chapter 9 he talks about session cookies being removed after the user closes down their browser. To make sure a user is logged in during subsequent visits a separate and persistent cookie can be created.

He described session cookies (as implemented by rails) as being secure. So the question is why have a session cookie that expires? I understand that it will no longer have to be called a session cookie and you would have to make sure the cookie was under the 4kb limit. A session cookie would then act as a secure "remember me" for the remainder of its life.

Why don't sites make their session cookies permanent?

Answer (score 3):

In the *Ruby on Rails tutorial*, he also told us the four main ways to steal cookies. Keep that in mind.

We have to distinguish two types of cookie. One is persistent, the other is per session.

[Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/223799/EN-US) defines them as:

> Persistent cookies are stored for a length of time that is set by the Web server when it passes the cookie to Internet Explorer. These cookies are used to store state information between visits to a site.
>
> Per-session cookies are used to store state information only within a session. These cookies are cached only while a user is visiting the Web server issuing the per-session cookie and are deleted from the cache when the user closes the session.

We use the persistent cookies to tell who the user is. Nevertheless, the expiration date is just up to you. You can set it whatever you like. But when it expires, the user have to log in again.

For the developers, maybe someone think it's more secure to let the user to remember and type it again and again.

Honestly, it would be much safer to ask the password when the user is doing something critical even after they logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the session is in fact persistent and many sites I have worked with have made them permanent and used them to log a user in and keep track of them.